# why matplotlib is not operating?

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I want to use matplotlib. I have installed it as:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

and in terminal I have:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.1'
>>> matplotlib.__file__
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.pyc'
 >>> mpl.get_configdir()
 '/home/azh2/.config/matplotlib'   
 >>>> mpl.get_cachedir()
 '/home/azh2/.cache/matplotlib'
```

now I want to use it. so in pycharm terminal I have:

```
$ from PIL import Image
from: can't read /var/mail/PIL
```

What is the problem please? can you help me solve it?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What makes you think this is matplotlib related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in **shell** not in **python** executing environment.